# PHP script feedback in webpage

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, apache

I am trying a build a web portal which runs a php script script that calls a batch file in windows, which in turn executes a powershell script that run powercli to fetch required info from vmware vcenter. All the result is sent to a file named f1.txt and f1.html sources this file and displays the output.All my codes are below.

The below solution works but, I have a requirement to display some output instead of a blank page when f1.php script is running and waiting for output from the underlying powershell script f1.bat -> f1.ps1.

Some progress report or direct feedback from the php script would do while the webpage is waiting the php script to finish.

For eg: Loading... with blinking dots or output from the script itself.

I have tried the flush() method and ob_flush() method in f1.php but it just gives me a blank screen with the output and once the php script completes running the nav bar gets loaded below that output.The page is all mangled.

How can I get the desired result with minimal code manipulation. If ajax or javascript is required for the task, then I'm open to that as well.

I have the below in index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
}
ul.nav li.dropdown-submenu:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
<div class="container-fluid">


            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">VMware VC Reports</a>
            </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Vcenters<span class=caret></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">San Jose Vcenter<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="http://mickey.example.com/view/f1.php">ESX Info</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="http://mickey.example.com/view/f2.php">Firmware Info</a></li>
        </li>
            </ul>

            </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
                    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the below in f1.php file.

```
<?php
system("f1.bat");
header("Location:http://mickey.example.com/view/f1.html");
exit;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
}
ul.nav li.dropdown-submenu:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
<div class="container-fluid">


            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">VMware VC Reports</a>
            </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Vcenters<span class=caret></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">San Jose Vcenter<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="http://mickey.example.com/view/f1.php">ESX Info</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="http://mickey.example.com/view/f2.php">Firmware Info</a></li>
        </li>
            </ul>

            </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
                    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the below in f1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
@media (min-width: 979px) {
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
}
ul.nav li.dropdown-submenu:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
<div class="container-fluid">


            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">VMware VC Reports</a>
            </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Vcenters<span class=caret></span></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">San Jose Vcenter<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="http://mickey.example.com/view/f1.php">ESX Info</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="http://mickey.example.com/view/f2.php">Firmware Info</a></li>
        </li>
            </ul>

            </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
                    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "f1.txt";
iframe.width = "20000";
iframe.height = "20000";
iframe.frameBorder = "0";
iframe.scrolling = "no";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
//-->
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is the question clear now or do you require more info?